# How can I write anchor tag in moodle form?

Tags: php, anchor, moodle

I have a **moodle form**. Inside the `form` I have to write an **anchor tag**. My form looks like this:

```
function definition() {
    global $DB;
    $mform =&$this->_form;
    $mform->addElement('editor', 'question', 'Question');
    $mform->addRule('question', null, 'required', null, 'client');
    $mform->setType('question', PARAM_RAW);

    //here I want an anchor tag

    $this->add_action_buttons(false, 'SAVE');
}
```

I want to write an `anchor tag` between text editor and button in the form.

I write anchor tag as

```
echo "<a href='/path/filename.txt' download='filename.txt'>filename.txt</a>";
```

but this displayed in top of the page. I want this `anchor` just below the editor field.(I can put position absolute/relative, but this makes some style issue and make no responsive)

Here I am using this `anchor` tag to download some file.

Please help me...My **moodle version is 2.9.1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to insert raw HTML into a Moodle form, using a 'static' element or using an 'html' element.

If you want a labelled link, then use a 'static' element:

```
$linkcontent = '<a href="/path/filename.txt">filename.txt</a>';
$mform->addElement('static', 'mylink', get_string('mylink', 'myplugin'), $linkcontent);
```

If you just want to put some arbitrary HTML content into the form:

```
$linkcontent = '<a href="/path/filename.txt">filename.txt</a>';
$mform->addElement('html', $linkcontent);
```

Notes: 'mylink' is just an arbitrary name to refer to the static element - it doesn't really matter what it is called, but it is best to make it unique (I've hit problems before when leaving this blank or having duplicates). The get_string part is to label the element in the same way that other form elements are labelled (if you don't need a label, then use the 'html' version instead).